# Java ArrayList thread unsafe example explanation

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

```
class ThreadUnsafe {

    static final int THREAD_NUMBER = 2;
    static final int LOOP_NUMBER = 200; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadUnsafe test = new ThreadUnsafe();
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMBER; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                test.method1(LOOP_NUMBER);
            }, "Thread" + i).start();
        }
    }

  
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void method1(int loopNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {  
            method2();
            method3();
        }
    }
    private void method2() {
        list.add("1");
    }
    private void method3() {
        list.remove(0);
    }

}
```

The code above throws

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 1
```

I know ArrayList is not thread-safe, but in the example, I think every remove() call is guaranteed to be preceded by at least one add() call, so the code should be OK even the order is messed up like the following:

```
thread0: method2()
thread1: method2()
thread1: method3()
thread0: method3()
```

Some explanations needed here, please.

Comment: ArrayList itself is not thread safe, so if two threads are doing add or remove calls concurrently bad things can happen.

Comment: Can you express a question please?

Comment: @Milgo Why it throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException? The code execution order can be messed up but I can not think of a case that an IndexOutOfBoundsException can happen.

Comment: @handhand The operations are not atomic, so while one is underway the state of the list is not well defined. As you yourself said, "ArrayList is not thread-safe". What do you think that means? If you want to see exactly what's happening, run your program under a debugger, with a breakpoint on IndexOutOfBoundsException. If you add the full stack trace someone might be able to tell you exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 7):

If always one `add()` or `remove()` call is completely finished before another one is started, your reasoning is correct. But `ArrayList` doesn't guarantee that as its methods aren't `synchronized`. So, it can happen that two threads are in the middle of some modifying calls at the same time.

Let's look at the internals of e.g. the `add()` method to understand one possible failure mode.

When adding an element, `ArrayList` increases the size using `size++`. And this is not atomic.

Now imagine the list being empty, and two threads A and B adding an element at exactly the same moment, doing the `size++` in parallel (maybe in different CPU cores). Let's imagine things happen in the following order:

- A reads size as 0.
- B reads size as 0.
- A adds one to its value, giving 1.
- B adds one to its value, giving 1.
- A writes its new value back into the `size` field, resulting in `size=1`.
- B writes its new value back into the `size` field, resulting in `size=1`.

Although we had 2 `add()` calls, the `size` is only 1. If now you try to remove 2 elements (and this time it happens sequentially), the second `remove()` will fail.

To achieve thread safety, no other thread should be able to mess around with the internals like `size` (or the elements array) while one access is currently in progress.

Multi-threading is inherently complex in that the calls from multiple threads can not only happen in any (expected or unexpected) order, but that they can also overlap, unless protected by some mechanism like `synchronized`. On the other hand, excessive use of the synchronization can easily lead to poor multi-thread performance, and also to dead-locks.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to [@RalfKleberhoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64279798/2402272),

> I think every remove() call is guaranteed to be preceded by at least one add() call,

Yes.

> so the code should be OK even the order is messed up

No, that is not a valid inference with respect to a multithreaded program.

Your program contains *data races* as a result of two threads both accessing the same shared, non-atomic object, with some of those accesses being writes, without appropriate synchronization.  The whole behavior of a program that contains data races is undefined, so in fact you cannot draw any conclusions at all about its behavior.

Do not try to cheat or scrimp on synchronization.  Do minimize the amount of it that you need by limiting your use of shared objects, but where you need it, you need it, and the rules for determining when and where you need it are not that hard to learn.

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in java docs says,

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
> access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the
> threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized
> externally.

Why this code is not thread safe ?

> Multiple thread running on Machine runs independent of each other.
>
> ```
>   public void method1(int loopNumber) {
>         for (int i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++) {  
>             method2();
>             method3();
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> Here `method2()` and `method3()` are being process **sequential within
> the thread** but **not across the thread**. ArrayList `list` is common between both thread. which will be  in **inconstant** state between both thread on multi core system.

Interesting test would be add empty check in `method3()` and set `LOOP_NUMBER = 10000`;

```
private void method3()
{
    if (!list.isEmpty())
        list.remove(0);
}
```

In result you should get same Runtime Exception some thing like `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 1` or `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` because of same reason **inconstant** state of variable in `list` i.e. `size`.

To fix this issue you could have added synchronized like below or use [Syncronized list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))

```
public void method1(int loopNumber)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < loopNumber; i++)
    {
        synchronized (list)
        {
            method2();
            method3();
        }
    }
}
```